# SSRS reports on EXCEL

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I'm trying to export a report to Excel from SSRS reports builder. When I export it to excel i don't want to re-organise the cell size to be able to see the entire data. I've tried using both tables and Textboxes for those cells to be exported as they are, neither worked.. any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: i'm nto sure if there's really a way to fix this.  you could try making everything wider, but i doubt that'll help.  Perhaps you could post a pic of your report, what it looks like going directly into excel, and then what you'd like it to come out as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it fixed. I had to manually expand the size in the reports builder and set 'can grow' and 'can shrink' to false for each text box. I understand that Excel doesn't support can Grow and can Shrink. Cheers